# is may you reply to my email grammatically correct?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, will-would, can-may

I'm curious if "May you" + verb is grammatically correct - any comments?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context, such as the whole sentence (or an example sentence) in which you use the construction in question? As it stands, it's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

#### Permission

The word “may” frequently refers to permission:

> You may stay out until nine, but you may not stay out past ten.

It can be used in this sense in questions. 
A couple of contrived examples:

> - May you swim in the ocean when there’s no lifeguard on duty?
> - If you roll an eight (on the dice),
>   may you choose to stop after moving only seven spaces?

These use “you” in the sense of “one”,
and, in real life, most people would use “can” instead of “may”;
e.g., “Can you swim…?”, “Can one swim…?”, or possibly “May one swim…?”

Sometimes “you” means just “you”:

> Now that you’ve moved into a larger apartment, may you get a dog?

but, again, this seems awkward. 
In real life, most people would ask, “are you allowed to get a dog?”

#### Wishes/Blessings

The word pair “may you” appears in non-questions,
that are somewhat similar to future declarative sentences,
but with a whiff of the prophetic to them. 
The classic example is:

> May you live in interesting times.

and it’s debatable whether that’s a wish or a curse. 
But there are plenty of blessings (wishes for good luck) that use those words. 
Here’s a nice one I found
at [Irish Quotations, Irish Blessings, Irish Proverbs and Irish Toasts](http://tacomaweekly.tripod.com/Irish-Quotations.html):

> May you always have walls for the winds,
> a roof for the rain, tea beside the fire,
> laughter to cheer you, those you love near you,
> and all your heart might desire.

#### If/Might

Delving deep into the Google results,
I found [this page](http://www.charlotteblakealston.com/programs) about Charlotte Blake Alston. 
Referring to the audience of a reading of a folk tale, it says,

> Tales that make you say, “Hmmm.”
>      ︙
> Not only may you find yourself asking, “What will Turtle do next?”
> you may also find yourself asking, “What would I do in that situation?” 
> Hmmm.

Here “may you” means “might you”, which essentially means “you might”.

---

All of these are grammatically correct
(although the ones in the first group are awkward and rarely used).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, polite form of a question is **could you**, but still may seems *grammatically* correct.